# Xsd2Code generation - SimpleTypes not generated when using option eit

Tags: c#, xsd, code-generation

I'm using Xsd2Code.exe to generate c# code from my xsd.

In my xsd I include another xsd and besides that I have some SimpleType declarations.
Now when I'm generating the code with the option "eit+" to exclude the included types, the SimpleTypes are not generated, either. When I don't have the option "eit+" set, the SimpleTypes are generated, but the included types are not excluded. But I need that.

Has somebody a solution for that? Or am I missing something? Thank you!